# Capturar evento "back" del navegador con Angular

Tags: angular, http

necesito ayuda con lo siguiente:

Desde un componente necesito saber si estoy llegando a él desde el botón "back" del navegador.

Es posible?

Estoy usando Angular 8.

Comment: Puedes agregar el código?

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con esto:

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

constructor(private _location: Location) {
}

onBack() {
   this._location.back();
}
```